# Programming languages complexity

Tags: programming-languages, complexity-theory

Is there an objective measure of a programming language's complexity **in terms of syntax and semantics, not how complex the language is to use**  ?

I've read many subjective comments but little rigorous analysis.

Comment: You should first define 'language's complexity'.

Comment: I'm guessing complexity of implementation rather than use

Comment: I wrote a Q/A over at cstheory SE on this very topic (if I read you right).  Search for Kolmogorov Quotient to measure programming language elegance or succinctness -- the ability a programming language has to simplify the complex..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Denotational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) and [operational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics):

> **Denotational semantics** is an approach to formalizing the meanings of programming languages by constructing mathematical objects (called denotations) which describe the meanings of expressions from the languages.

> The **operational semantics** for a programming language describes how a valid program is interpreted as sequences of computational steps. These sequences then are the meaning of the program. In the context of functional programs, the final step in a terminating sequence returns the value of the program. (In general there can be many return values for a single program, because the program could be nondeterministic, and even for a deterministic program there can be many computation sequences since the semantics may not specify exactly what sequence of operations arrives at that value.)

Answer (score 10):

Language's [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is a rough measure - just for a taste :-)

A few examples,

- [C++](http://www.externsoft.ch/download/cpp-iso.html)
- [Scheme](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_9.html)
- [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8)
- [Ada](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~adagroup/ada95-syntax/BNFindex.html)
- [Haskell](http://www.hck.sk/users/peter/HaskellEx.htm)

Comment: These are nice. Is there a readable one somewhere for Haskell?

Comment: Added Ada's. Feel free to take it back out if you don't want your list to grow, Nick.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear to me that complexity is even a well-defined term when applied to a programming language.

If by "objective" you mean "quantitative", you could ask such questions as

- How big is an unambiguous grammar?
- How big is a working yacc grammar?

Since almost no language has a formal semantics, it's hard to do any quantitative studies.  But you could ask

- How big is the simplest interpreter for the language, relative to interpreters for other languages that use the same metalanguage (language in which the interpreter is written)?  This measure is somewhat related to Kolmogorov complexity.

Except as a matter of curiosity, it's not clear to me that this question is worth asking—it's hard to imagine useful answers.

Comment: You could add number of AST traversals required and other translation metrics.

Answer (score 3):

The best measure I've seen of a language is the probability that a random string will be a valid program.  Perl is a language that ranks high on this scale, Ada ranks rather low.

What this metric *means* is another issue entirely.

Comment: THe proud boast of the TECO editor was that any string of characters when treated as a command would do something. This is one of many reasons you don't see many TECO users around these days.

Comment: The reason for this is if the first (or one of the first?) tokens is __END__ then ANYTHING produced after that is a valid Perl program. This alone has Perl in the lead for having a slice of infinite sequences that are valid programs.

Comment: @Neil: Emacs started life as a TECO front-end, so it lives on in spirit.

Comment: It is not complexity, it measures operator length. Java would also be low.

Answer (score 3):

As a **general rule**, the more **dynamic and abstracted** the syntax or semantics or implementation are, the more complex the language (not to use as you stated).

Hence, Java is a more complex language than C, because:

1. C has simple scoping rules vs Java's relatively complex rules
2. Types are more complex, method resolution and overloading
3. Things like inheretance, argument enumeration and checking, method overloading make the compilation process much more complex.

I would argue Python simpler than Java on this basis, because it's object model, whilst complex, is simple in terms of reduction into a simpler form. The ease in which a given syntax can be **translated into a simpler form** from a time and calculation perspective might also be an angle.

A language such as **lisp** on the other hand, some would argue is **complex to use** but very simple. The same goes for things like Haskell.

You could measure complexity in one of the following ways, but non are complete:

1. The number of keywords, lines of code and the complexity of semantics (like identifier resolution) for a simple problem. Fibonacci computation might be one. Comparing agreeably efficient implementation of common algorithms.
2. What happens when? Are names **bound late** at runtime, or are they resolved at compile-time?
3. Could a given snippet of code be understood in more than one way, when not given all the facts of the identifiers, types and external code?

There are **tons of ways**. You could measure computational complexity of the compilation process for a given syntax.

Not all of these examples are true. Some object models are very complex, but very fast because they use a fast foundation. Self might be an example.

Answer (score 1):

I love Project Euler for evaluating this. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest two entirely objective things to look at would be the amount of languaged defined symbols and keywords/reserved words, and the amount of productions in its BNF.

Another thing you could look at, for those languages that have them, is the relative sizes of their standards documents. Some would argue that not all standard documents are written at the same level, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you look in the area of proof-of-correctness you'll find more detailed analysis of semantic complexity. Systems like CSP (and to a lesser extent, Lambda Calculus) are designed to be tractable via analysis. The closer a language is to being an expression of the underlying formal system, the simpler it is from a semantic standpoint.

The counter-example would be something like the C programming language. It's not possible to figure out what a C program actually does, without knowing what OS and hardware it'll be run on.

Answer (score 1):

As other users posted, keywords are an objective measure of how complex a programming language can be. The grammar/syntax would describe how complex the code structure can be (allowed keyword combinations). There are software quality related code metrics to measure how complex a piece of code is.

Semantical complexity seems to me harder to measure. It is related to expressive power (the higher the programming language level the more expressive power). I see no point on trying to compare different solutions implemented in different languages in order to measure their expressive power (i.e. using Euler project problem implementations = solutions). The problem itself and each programming language paradigm can bias the comparison.

In case of high level programming languages, I presume that the number of possible implementations for a specific problem (from an abstract point of view) is a good measure of semantical complexity.

In case of low level programming languages, it could be interesting looking at how specification languages generate code (find an implementation = solution for the given problem). Regardless of this, due to the limited abstraction this measure seems to be closely related to software quality code metrics.

As you can see abstraction and semantical complexity is harder to automate (generate an implementation = solution given the specification). There is where the programmer's knowledge, intelligence and psychology comes in (AI hasn't reached this point).

Answer (score 0):

How complex the language is to use is somewhat subjective.

On the other hand, questions about how complex the language semantics are, can be answered, but only when compared with other languages. These are not necessarily useful, however. For example, I would give Smalltalk a semantic complexity of 1 and C++ a complexity of 9. However, I will bet anything that the browser you are reading this in is written 
in C++, not Smalltalk.

Answer (score -1):

If there is such an objective measure, it is probably very nearly useless for evaluating the utility or cost of using a given language for a given purpose. It'd help you rule out whitespace or brainfuck, but that can be done just as easily without expending resources on such an objective measure—by subjectively observing source code and realizing you'd never want to do serious work with it.

Most languages are going to have a lot of positives and negatives that you'd need to weigh against the goal you're trying to achieve and the conditions that need to be met.

Comment: I sure wish SO required a comment on downvote. People, if you don't like an answer, explain why.